# Error while build SyntaxNet with Bazel

Tags: ubuntu, build, tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I am trying to run Syntaxnet on Ubuntu in my VirtualBox following instructions on [SyntaxNet Github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/32ab5a58dd3714d0747da6993a01315dadbf0e0f/syntaxnet#installation)

When i ran "bazel test syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...", all test targets were skipped. The error codes are as below.[image: Error codes while building SyntaxNet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are seeing:

```
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
```

...is usually caused by GCC running out of memory. There are two main options for fixing this:

1. Limit the number of parallel jobs using Bazel's [`--jobs`](http://www.bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#flag--jobs) flag.
2. Limit the resources used with Bazel's [`--local_resources`](http://www.bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#flag--local_resources) flag.

The best configuration will depend on your particular machine, but something like the following has been [known to work in the past](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1530#issuecomment-197880922) (for building TensorFlow):

```
bazel test syntaxnet/... util/utf8/... --local_resources 2048,2.0,1.0 --jobs 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was indeed the problem.
I increased the RAM of my Virtualbox and limited bazel's resources.